# how to set PHP confirmation dialog box before save and after form validation in single page

Tags: php, dialog, box, confirmation

How to set the popup confirmation dialog box once the form validation is done in php? If user clicks the submit button, it should validate the user input then, finally it will ask the confirmation message like "Do you want to save?" with ok and cancel buttons, then only it should save the data into database.
please refer below code.

```
 <?php
    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );
    $name_err='';
    $name='';
    $type_err='';
    $type='';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

              $e = true;

        if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
            $name_err = "Please enter the Product Name";
            $e = false;
        } else {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            // check if name only contains letters and whitespace

        }
     if (empty($_POST['type'])||$_POST['type']=="select") {
            $type_err = "Please select the Product Type";
            $e = false;
        } else {
            $type = $_POST['type'];

                   }
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "csr");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }


}
//final check whether it is true the input will process

    if($e)
    {

        mysqli_select_db($con, "csr");

        mysqli_query($con, "insert into products(employee_id, name, type, brand, model, url, conditions, about, listedon, image_path, reserved_price, Purchased_price, buy_now_price, sale_end_date)
                                   values('$eid','$name','$type','$brand','$model','None','$condition','$about','$listedon','$imgName','$reserved_price','$Purchased_price','$buy_now_price','$sale_end_date')") or  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

        header('Location:/sellproduct/index/');
        mysqli_close($con);

    }
}
?>
 <form action=" "  method="post" class="stdform stdform2" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <p>
                             <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="" id="employee_id" />
                    </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" class="required">Product Name</label>
                    <span class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /><br><span class="error"><?php echo $name_err;?></span></span>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="type" class="required">Product Type</label>
                    <span class="field">
                    <select name="type" id="type" minlength="2" maxlength="60">
                            <option value="select" label="Select" <?php echo ($type == "select" || empty($type) ? "selected='selected'" : "");  ?> selected disabled >Select</option>
                            <option value="Electronics" label="Electronics" <?php echo ($type == "Electronics" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Electronics</option>
                            <option value="Appliances" label="Appliances" <?php echo ($type == "Appliances" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Appliances</option>
 <form action=" "  method="post" class="stdform stdform2" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <p>
                             <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="" id="employee_id" />
                    </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" class="required">Product Name</label>
                    <span class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /><br><span class="error"><?php echo $name_err;?></span></span>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="type" class="required">Product Type</label>
                    <span class="field">
                    <select name="type" id="type" minlength="2" maxlength="60">
                            <option value="select" label="Select" <?php echo ($type == "select" || empty($type) ? "selected='selected'" : "");  ?> selected disabled >Select</option>
                            <option value="Electronics" label="Electronics" <?php echo ($type == "Electronics" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Electronics</option>
                            <option value="Appliances" label="Appliances" <?php echo ($type == "Appliances" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Appliances</option>
 <form action=" "  method="post" class="stdform stdform2" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <p>
                             <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" value="" id="employee_id" />
                    </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="name" class="required">Product Name</label>
                    <span class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" /><br><span class="error"><?php echo $name_err;?></span></span>

                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="type" class="required">Product Type</label>
                    <span class="field">
                    <select name="type" id="type" minlength="2" maxlength="60">
                            <option value="select" label="Select" <?php echo ($type == "select" || empty($type) ? "selected='selected'" : "");  ?> selected disabled >Select</option>
                            <option value="Electronics" label="Electronics" <?php echo ($type == "Electronics" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Electronics</option>
                            <option value="Appliances" label="Appliances" <?php echo ($type == "Appliances" ? "selected='selected'" : ""); ?>>Appliances</option>
</select><br><span class="error"><?php echo $type_err;?></span></span>                </p>

<p class="stdformbutton">
                    <input type="submit" class="bluishBtn button_small" name="submit" value="SAVE" id="submit">

                    <button name="cancel" id="cancel" type="button" class="greyishBtn button_small">Cancel</button>                </p>

</form>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate a dialog box directly by PHP, in your final if statement, you should echo a basic html with a javascript which redirects to another php page taking your input in argument to insert it :

```
echo '

<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

function input_confirm(){

    var r = confirm("Confirm this input : '.$_POST['name'].'-'.$_POST['type'].'");
    if(r){
        window.location.href = "insert.php?type='.$_POST['type'].'&name='.$_POST['name'].'";
    }
}


</script>

<body onload="input_confirm()">
</body>

</html>

';
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, It is not asking any confirm box and it is not taking input as well.

Comment: I just corrected the code. There was a mistake since the function was also called confirm. I just tried, now it should work :-)

Comment: Thank you very much.....Have a great day!!!

Comment: You too, please don't forget to check my comment as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes....It is working good....I have one  more problem, please refer the below url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043094/datatables-warning-json-data-from-server-could-not-be-parsed-this-is-a-caused

Comment: Then mark my answer as good please.

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal solution is to make two validations - on a client and on a server side. There is no need to bothering server with invalid data which could be pre validated on a client machine.

For a client side validation you need to write some javascript which will validate form after user clicks **Submit** button. Of course **Submit** button must be standard type button, you don't want it to actually submit but just to call javascript validation function. You can use validate.js for that if you want.

So, validation function, after doing it's job, displays pop up with question whether to save data or not or... different pop up with info that the form need to be corrected. Place those two forms in invisible DIV blocks and display them when needed.
Now in a question pop up the **OK** button calls another javascript function which now makes an ajax call to the server sending all the form data.

If your validation depends on some database state or anything which lays on server, you can make one additional ajax call in validation function to ask the server for some more info or even ask it to validate some fields instantly. This is useful for example if you have registration form and want to immediately display info to the user that a nickname is already in use so he can change it before even pressing **Sumbit**.

Then upon receiving this data by the server you **need** to make another server side validation to check for data integrity and possible attacks.

Hope this helps. Btw, if you need to make such actions in a single page I really recommend to implement jQuery and validate.js.